# Analytic Extension of bounded real analytic functions to complex analytic ones

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, analyticity, analytic-functions, analytic-continuation

If a real analytic function $f$ is bounded on real line $\Bbb R$: given a finite open strip containing $\Bbb R$, does there always exist a holomporphic function $h$ which is bounded on the given finite strip, such that $h = f$ on real line?

Answer (score 3):

No. You can't extend$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb R&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\dfrac1{1+x^2}\end{array}$$analytically to the strip $\left\{z\in\mathbb C\,\middle|\,\operatorname{Im}z\in(-2,2)\right\}$.

Comment: What if there are no poles in C?

Comment: The domain of the original function is $\mathbb R$, and therefore it makes no sense to assert that it has (or hasn't) poles outside $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

If you meant

> Given $f$ analytic and bounded on $\Bbb{R}$ can it be extended to a function analytic and bounded on some  horizontal strip $|\Im(z)| < r$

then the answer is no, look at
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-n}}{z-n-\frac{i}n}$$
having some poles on every horizontal strip $|\Im(z)| < r$.

If you meant

> Given $g$ entire and bounded on $\Bbb{R}$ is it bounded on some  horizontal strip $|\Im(z)| < r$

then the answer is no, look at $$g(z) = e^{iz^2}, \qquad |g(a-ib)| = e^{2ab},\qquad h(z)=2\cos(z^2),\qquad|2\cos(z^2)|\ge e^{2|ab|}-1$$

Comment: Nice! You cleared most cases. Consider this last case, IF  meromorphic extension of a real bounded analytic function turns out to be entire (like sinx) , Is it necessary that this entire function is always bounded on any finite strip strip containg R?

Comment: ?? This is my second case

Comment: But it is not real valued on R.

Comment: Come on, it is completely obvious that $\cos(z^2)$ is real valued on $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: hmm ? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Perfect, cos(z^2) works, this will serve a better immediate counter example to the question, otherwise your answer seems to avoid  either enitreness or real valued on R on first glance.

Comment: Because it is obvious $\cos(z^2)$ works and real analytic doesn't mean "real valued and analytic". Entire means complex analytic on $\Bbb{C}$ (which implies by Cauchy's integral formula that it is given by a single power series)

Comment: My question was ofcourse a stronger statement, I understand what is real analytic, real, analytic and entire. Your counter examples were appropriate,  up to the question. It just seemed that one was trying to avoid entireness or real valued on R which hinted that my weaker statement might still hold. Thats it. No big deal. You were ofcourse right all the time. And my bad, I couldn't come up with the obvious example. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

For $f(z)=e^{iz^2},$ we have $|f(x+iy)|=e^{-2xy}.$ Thus $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb R,$ but on every horizontal line below the real axis, $f$ blows up exponentially as $x\to \infty.$